# unique x500 object id creation

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to create a unique x500 object id for active directory to extend the schema.
I have been allocated a PEN as per [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers).

This number is only 5 digits longs. All the examples I have seen the OID is a lot longer. IE 1.2.840.113556.1.8000.999999

Any links or directions on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that was slightly lost with this, this is what I have found out. 
I was missing the 1.3.6.1.4.1 at the beginning which is global as per the original link in the question.
My OID ended up being 1.3.6.1.4.1.52051.10000.1.1.1